# Orange vs NLTK for Content Classification in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, naivebayes, orange

We need a content classification module. Bayesian classifier seems to be what I am looking for. Should we go for Orange or NLTK ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well as evidenced by the documentation, the Naive Bayes implementation in each Library is easy
to use, so why not run your data with both and compare the results?

Both Orange and NLTK are both mature, stable libraries (10+ years in development for each library) 
that originated in large universities; they share some common features primarily Machine Learning 
algorithms. Beyond that, they are quite different in scope, purpose, and implementation.

Orange is domain agnostic--not directed towards a particular academic discipline
or commercial domain, instead it advertises itself as full-stack data mining 
and ML platform.  It's focus is on the ***tools*** themselves and not the application of those tools in a particular discipline.

Its features include IO, the data analysis algorithm, and 
a data visualization canvas.

NLTK, on the other hand, began as and remains an academic project in a computational 
linguistics department of a large university. The task you mentioned
(document content classification) and your algorithm of choice (Naive Bayesian)
are pretty much right at the core of NLTK's functionality. NLTK does indeed 
have ML/Data Mining algorithms but its only because they have a particular 
utility in computational linguistics.

NLTK of course includes some ML algorithms but only because they have utility in computational linguistics, along with document parsers, tokenizers, part-of-speech 
analyzers, etc.--all of which comprise NLTK.

Perhaps the Naive Bayes implementation in Orange is just as good, i would still choose NLTK's 
implementation because it is clearly optimized for the particular task you mentioned.

There are numerous tutorials on NLTK and in particular for its Naive Bayes for use
content classification. A blog post by [Jim Plus](http://www.litfuel.net/plush/?postid=200) and another in [streamhacker.com](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/), for instance present excellent 
tutorials for the use of NLTK's Naive Bayes; the second includes a line-by-line 
discussion of the code required to access this module. The authors of both of these
posts report good results using NLTK (92% in the former, 73% in the latter).

Comment: Always amazed by the depth of answers I get here, thanks.

Comment: I am a total rookie in this field. What we want to do is to classify content into categories based on features found in the text, even if the category name is not one of the features. (Want to classify orange as a fruit event if the word "fruit" is not in the text.) Should we be looking for a specific type of classification or is Naive Bayes what we're looking for ?

Comment: I should maybe add that the outcome should be multiple categories. Does that defeat the purpose of Naive Bayes ? Is the Fisher method more appropriate is such case ?

Comment: Here's my answer to an SO question on Naive Bayes, which should be right on target.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Orange, but +1 for NLTK:

I've successively used the classification tools in NLTK to classify text and related meta data. Bayesian is the default but there are other alternatives such as Maximum Entropy. Also being a toolkit, you can customize as you see fit - eg. creating your own features (which is what I did for the meta data).

NLTK also has a couple of good books - one of which is available under Creative Commons (as well as O'Reilly).

Answer (score 1):

NLTK is a toolkit that supports a four state model of natural language processing:

1. Tokenizing: grouping characters as words. This ranges from trivial regex stuff to dealing with contractions like "can't"
2. Tagging. This is applying part-of-speech tags to the tokens (eg "NN" for noun, "VBG" for verb gerund). This is typically done by training a model (eg Hidden Markov) on a training corpus (i.e. large list of by by hand tagged sentences).
3. Chunking/Parsing. This is taking each tagged sentence and extracting features into a tree (eg noun phrases). This can be according to a hand-written grammar or a one trained on a corpus.
4. Information extraction. This is traversing the tree and extracting the data. This is where your specific orange=fruit would be done.

NLTK supports WordNet, a huge semantic dictionary that classifies words. So there are 5 noun definitions for orange (fruit, tree, pigment, color, river in South Africa). Each of these has one or more 'hypernym paths' that are hierarchies of classifications. E.g. the first sense of 'orange' has a two paths:

- orange/citrus/edible_fruit/fruit/reproductive_structure/plant_organ/plant_part/natural_object/whole/object/physical_entity/entity

and

- orange/citrus/edible_fruit/produce/food/solid/matter/physical_entity/entity

Depending on your application domain you can identify orange as a fruit, or a food, or a plant thing. Then you can use the chunked tree structure to determine more (who did what to the fruit, etc.)